# How can I have the JS/CSS cache refresh on every page load?

Tags: theming, performance, debugging

How to clear cache on every page load?

I am doing CSS & JS theming and currently having to manually clear cache (using devel module) every time and then reload the page again to see my changes?

How do I do it so that in every page load cache is cleared?

Comment: @Nikhil - Your solution works too. Thanks. I ended up just using areynolds idea as it was easier for this specific need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't have *JS* or *CSS aggregation* turned on, you shouldn't have to clear cache to see your changes to existing files. You can see this settings by going to;

*Admin->Config->Development->Performance(`admin/config/development/performance`).*

If you are adding new *CSS* or *JS* files, you'll probably have to clear cache to register them with the theme system.

If you really want to clear cache on every page load, you should create a custom module that implements *hook_init()* and runs *drupal_clear_css_cache()* and *drupal_clear_js_cache()* (or any other cache clearing functions you may want), but this should be unnecessary.

Comment: And it s not probably cached in Drupal but in browser, a simple `Ctrl F5` in browser will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you disabled caching in Drupal (Performance) and still files are not reloaded, it's probably cached by your web browser.

Some web browser can force the cache reload by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

In Chrome internal caching can be disabled in DevTools settings (<kbd>F1</kbd> once you open *Developers Tools*), then: *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)*.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This is not a perfect solution. 
But you can use this in dev stages

Copy/Paste this code in your themes template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $base_root
  include_once $base_root.'/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

Try and let me know the status.

Comment: This is terrible for performance. You are much better to simply un-preproccess the JS and CSS for development.

Comment: @wiifm OP asked for it, and as i stated **This is not a perfect solution. But you can use this in dev stages**