# How can you force a stylesheet reload in Drupal7?

Tags: .info, theming

This is about that old trick of tacking a fake query argument onto the URL of a stylesheet (e.g., `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/site.css?v=123">`) so that, when you change the stylesheet, it'll be reloaded by the users' browsers, since it looks like a URL that's not in the browser's cache.

So, the question: How can you do this in D7 where the stylesheets are specified in the .info files?  I tried adding a query arg onto the entry in my site's info file -- `stylesheets[all][] = site.css?v=123` but without any luck (the page rendering got very unhappy).  Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [How can I have the JS/CSS cache refresh on every page load?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/48336/1908)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default you can navigate to `/admin/config/development/performance` and select the <kbd>Clear all caches</kbd> button. Behind the scenes this will actually do what you describe by appending a new query-string to the CSS URL.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush)

```
$ drush help cache-clear
Clear a specific cache, or all drupal caches.

Arguments:
 type                                      The particular cache to clear. Omit 
                                           this argument to choose from        
                                           available caches.                   


Aliases: cc
```

So you can do

```
drush cc css-js
```

and this will rescan the cached CSS and JS files, nuke them if they are stale, and generate a new key that gets appended to CSS and JS URLs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this _only_ clears the CSS and JS files, not the whole cache.

Comment: I believe page caches should be cleared afterwards as well, otherwise cached pages would be referencing stale CSS/JS aggregate files.

Answer (score 5):

Flushing the Drupal caches should take care of this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your changes made to your theme.info file by issuing the 'theme-list' cache clear Drush command:

```
$ drush cc theme-list
```

you can also add this line to theme.info to force rebuilding cache on every page load:

```
settings[clear_registry] = 1
```