# Issue with drupal cache

Tags: entities, blocks, caching, views

I have developed website using drupal 7. I created block using Views Slideshow Cycle. I uploaded the site to server. The slideshow not displayed in live site. But after clearing cache(using configuration->Development->Performance) the slideshow is visible.The problem is that i need to clear the cache frequently to display the slideshow. **The below image is the site without slideshow.**[image: slideshow not visible]

**This is the site with slideshow after clearing cache.**[image: slideshow is visible after clearing cache]

I am also having hidden fields using field permission. That are also visible to anonymous users. But I gave the field view permission only to authenticated users. Those fields are hidden for anonymous user after clearing cache.
I didn't enabled cache pages and cache blocks. But the site in my local system does not have this issue.
These issue only with my live site. My hosting server is apache.
I have this problem for a month. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the in the Views Caching you have enabled "Site Wide Caching". 

The view is being cached for anonymous user and anonymous user doesn't have the permission to View the slide show.

Comment: hi @gokul-n-k, As I already mentioned, I disabled the cache pages and cache blocks in Performance settings. The slideshow is not displayed for administrator also. After clearing cache only the slideshow block is visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have the JS/CSS cache refresh on every page load?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48336/how-can-i-have-the-js-css-cache-refresh-on-every-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue when views, javascript and caching are used in combination. 
Some information that may be of help:

https://drupal.org/node/1873970
https://drupal.org/node/1811828
https://drupal.org/node/1984774

As far a I can understand the cached page or block cause the js to fail. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788138/jquery-flexslider-not-loading-everytime) it is stated:

> This may be a timing issue, flexslider may require the images to be
>   loaded when it is called so it can work off their attributes, remember
>   that $(document).ready() fires after the DOM has finished loading
>   whilst $(window).load() fires after all images on the page have loaded
>   - giving you intermittent results if they are cached etc, replace:
>
> $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); with
>
> $(window).load(function(){ ... });

I have not found a sure fire answer /solution to the issue and may broaden out the question to see if there is an advised fix for views+cache+js=problem.